# Can I store my Kobo library on a PC to prevent lengthy download times

Tags: kobo, library

Downloading my library each time I plug in to my account is eating into monthly download allocation.  Can these books be kept on my PC instead of in cloud?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

- Download & install Adobe Digital Editions (http://www.adobe.com/solutions/ebook/digital-editions/download.html).
- Follow the instructions [here](https://www.kobo.com/help/en-US/article/3501/using-adobe-digital-editions)